# Ruby on rails devise for authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman

I have used **Devise gem** for authentication, Everything is working fine. But now i want to call one of the controller action from **postman** service. Am getting problem for login from **postman** to our application. How can i resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simple token authentication [gem](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) which works with devise, provides the ability to manage an authentication_token from your model instances. A model with that ability enabled is said to be token authenticatable

In the initializers for simple token authentication you can configure the Headers for which the devise should look for authentication parameters.

Add  `acts_as_token_authenticatable` to your model like `User` in this case.

Add authentication token attribute to the model(User)

```
rails g migration add_authentication_token_to_users "authentication_token:string{30}:uniq"
rake db:migrate
```

In the application controller add the following

```
acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User
```

In simple_token_authentication initializer , you can configure the settings

```
config.header_names = { user: { authentication_token: 'X-User-Token', email: 'X-User-Email' } }
```

are defaults.

Comment: Do i need to remove **before_action :authenticate_user!** line in application controller?

Comment: no, you need to keep that to make sure that requests are authenticated on very call.

Comment: I successfully created the authenticity token for user model. And am sending token from postman request but still its saying unauthorized user. Can you please help on this

Comment: can post how you are sending the request headers through the postman.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Postman sync to synchronize data on browser and postman.